# Fullcalendar v5 "dateClick" method off by a day?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using FullCalendar v5.  I have a [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sevenreeds/wf5soq8L/39/).  As I write this it is October 2020.  If I visit the calendar at the fiddle and click on Sunday, Oct 4 the `dateClick` method will send up an alert box with the date for Saturday, Oct 3.  Have I misconfigured something?

**EDIT**

Let me describe this differently.  On the fiddle page (you may have to significantly increase the output screen size) There is a month view.  There are date blocks with events and some without.  Pick a date cell without events and click in the cell.

When I do this (several different browsers on Windows and Linux platforms and a pixel phone) the `dateClick` function is triggered and a javascript alert comes up to report the `info.date` value in the function.  I expect that the date of the clicked item will be displayed.  What I see is the date of the day *before* the day cell I click.

This behaviour can appear to be different if you click in a cell with listed events.  In cells that have so many events that the overrun is hidden by a "+n more" line if you click the "+n" line then a small popup appears with the extra items and a **correct** date in the popup.  Instead, click in the same date cell away from the events and the alert will appear with the previous day's date date displayed.

dateClick function:

```
dateClick: function(info) {
  window.alert(`dateClick: ${info.date.toString()}`);
},
```

Here is what I get after clicking on Oct 4:
[image]

Comment: The fiddle isn't reproducing that problem for me. Maybe you have some sort of timezone issue?

Comment: Hmm, just edited the question.  hopefully more details. I and another person have now seen the issue in multi-browsers on multi-platforms.

Comment: Sorry but I still can't reproduce it - see my results at https://i.imgur.com/U9Dl6PI.gif . What **exact** output are you getting in each alert? I still wonder if there's somehow a timezone issue. Can't think what else it would be.

Comment: Here is what I get after clicking on Oct 4:  https://imgur.com/nxeYEw8

Comment: As I suspected it's a timezone issue. Oct 3 1900 CDT is the same as Oct 4 0000 UTC. fullCalendar tells you the time in UTC. Your browser has translated that to your local timezone when you stringify the date object (hence why I see the date "correctly" because my timezone (BST) happens to be 1hr ahead of UTC).

Comment: I don't know for sure (since I didn't write it) but I'd suspect that's why the info object also gives you a pure string property `dateStr` containing only the date part, which hopefully is correctly processed to give you the physically clicked date no matter your timezone - try this version and see if it does the job: https://jsfiddle.net/42mfzvy8/ (I can't easily verify the results for obvious reasons!).

Comment: Thank you.  My assumption was that the timezone config option would auto-convert.

Comment: No, the timezone option does affect things but not quite perhaps how you're expecting - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-object for more details. The timezone article also explains a bit too

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really @ADyson's: FC uses UTC datetimes and I was not interpreting them correctly.